# handling null and string.empty using ?? operator in C#

Tags: c#

I want to handle "" and null while assigning value to the property of the class.

So how can i handle the same. Below is my example which works for null. But also want to handle empty string

```
 Id = characater.Id ?? System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
```

Comment: `??` only works with null. Use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` with `?:` operator

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourstring)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [string.IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) along with the [?: Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).

```
Id = string.IsNullOrEmpty(characater.Id) 
  ? System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() 
  : characater.Id;
```

---

If you you also want to check for white space characters line spaces, line breaks, tabs, you can use [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.